# JS todo list item checked, and add item

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am aiming to create a JS todo list similar to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

I have created the basic structure of my todo list application and the function of the close buttons.
These are working well, but I have a problem with adding new todo list items and checking and unchecking todo items.
I'm not sure if I'm using the classlist toggle property well, and also cannot figure why the add button doesn't work at all.

```js
var todoitemlist = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');

var i;
for (i = 0; i < todoitemlist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.innerHTML = "Close";
  span.className = "closebutton";
  todoitemlist[i].appendChild(span);
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebutton");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var listitem = this.parentElement;
    listitem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
var todoitemlistx = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');
//checked element
var i;
for (i = 0; i < todoitemlistx.length; i++) {
  todoitemlistx[i].onclick = function(ev) {
    ev.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    ev.classList.toggle("todo-item-checked");
  }
}

//add another list item
function add() {
  var listitem = document.createElement("LI");
  listitem.className = "todo-item";
  var text = document.getElementById('todoinput').value;
  var myul = getElementById('todo-list');
  var t = document.createTextNode(text);
  listitem.appendChild(t);
  myul.appendChild(listitem);

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  span.innerHTML = "Close";
  span.className = "closebutton";
  listitem[i].appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #dbf9fc;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 27, 39);
}

#todoinput {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 65%;
}

#add-button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 27, 39);
  color: #dbf9fc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 1fr;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#add-button:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

#todo-list {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 70%;
}

.todo-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.closebutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  background-color: #e6772d;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
}

.closebutton:hover {
  background-color: #c46526;
}

.todo-item-checked {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<main class="centered">
  <h1>ToDo List JS</h1>
  <h3>js project</h3>
  <form action="">

    <input type="text" name="" id="todoinput" placeholder="Enter the activity you've wented to do">
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="add-button" onclick="add()">
  </form>
  <ul id="todo-list">
    <li class="todo-item">
      Hit the lights
    </li>
    <li class="todo-item">
      Hit the lights
    </li>
    <li class="todo-item">
      Hit the lights
    </li>
    <li class="todo-item-checked todo-item">
      Hit the lights
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: Run the snippet and fix the errors. You are for example missing a document. in front of one of the getElementById. BE CONSISTENT

Comment: You have listItem, but here you try to append to listItem[i]: `listitem[i].appendChild(span);`

Comment: Also PLEASE delegate: `document.getElementById('todo-list').addEventListener('click', function(e) { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.classList.contains('closebutton')) tgt.closest('li').remove() });`

Answer (score 1):

I remember what it was like starting development and how hard it could be, so I persevered with this.
I thought it would be a few small changes but it turned into a massive rewrite.

Una grande padulo, as the Italians like to say.

I hope you can or try to understand what I did here.

The big lesson would be, don't write the same code twice, put it in a separate function.

So this seems to work.
Let me know if it doesn't.

```
 var todoitemlist=document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');

 for(var i=0;i<todoitemlist.length;i++)
 {
  myawesomeclosebutton(todoitemlist[i]);
  todoitemlist[i].addEventListener('click',myawesomebackground);
 }

 function myawesomeclosebutton(myawesomeitem)
 {
  var span=document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML='Close';
  span.className='closebutton';
  span.addEventListener('click',myawesomecloseevent);
  myawesomeitem.appendChild(span);
 }

 function myawesomebackground(ev)
 {
  if(ev.target.style.backgroundColor!='red')
  {
   ev.target.style.backgroundColor='red';
  }
  else
  {
   ev.target.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
  }
 }

 function myawesomecloseevent(event)
 {
  var div=event.target.parentElement;
  div.style.display='none';
 }

 function add()
 {
  var listitem=document.createElement('li');
  listitem.className='todo-item';
  var myawesomeinput=document.getElementById('todoinput');
  var text=myawesomeinput.value;
  var myul=document.getElementById('todo-list');
  var t=document.createTextNode(text);
  listitem.appendChild(t);
  myul.appendChild(listitem);
  listitem.addEventListener('click',myawesomebackground);
  myawesomeclosebutton(listitem);
  myawesomeinput.value='';
 }
```